# Getting path of project or layer file in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgs, directory

I am generating new raster files from vector layers on a project. I would like to save them in the same directory as the project or layer files.

How do I find this path using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Python console:

```py
QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") # also try "../"
```

Or with

```
dir(QgsProject.instance())
```

you find something like

```
fileName()
```

---

For Python plugin (not tested!):

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
from qgis.core import QgsProject

path_absolute = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
QMessageBox.information(None, "Title", "AP: " + unicode(path_absolute))
```

Answer (score 21):

To access a vector file path, on a active layer, this code works well in Python Console:

```
>>>import os
>>>myfilepath= iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
>>>myfilepath
u'/home/zeito/tiznados_canoa.tif'
>>>(myDirectory,nameFile) = os.path.split(myfilepath)
>>>myDirectory
u'/home/zeito'
>>>nameFile
u'tiznados_canoa.tif'
```

It was tested with my 'tiznados_canoa.tif' raster as a active layer.

Comment: Be aware in case of vector layer the path after file name contains also pipe and layer id (C:/shapes/test.shp|layerid=0). I use path = path [:path.rfind('|')] to remove it.

Answer (score 13):

### In QGIS 3.2 and above:

**Project path:**

```py
QgsProject.instance().fileName() 
# OR
QgsProject.instance().absoluteFilePath() # C:/test/sample_project.qgz
```

**Project folder path:**

```py
QgsProject.instance().homePath()
# OR
QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()   # C:/test
```

### In QGIS 2.x, 3.0 and 3.1:

**Project path:**

```py
QgsProject.instance().fileName()  # C:/test/sample_project.qgs
```

**Project folder path:**

```py
QgsProject.instance().homePath() # C:/test
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access a vector file path, on a active layer, this seems to work:

```
myfilepath= os.path.dirname( unicode( qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri() ) ) ;
fic = myfilepath + "[% "FILE" %]"
```

then to open a picture or text located in same directory as mylayer:

```
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit, QtCore ; vue=QtWebKit.QWebView() vue.setUrl( QtCore.QUrl( fic ) ) ; vue.show()
```

Comment: Useful answer but what about the file name? You use "[% "FILE" %]" but I don't understand what does it means...

Answer (score 6):

I did test this on QGIS 3.4:

```py
QgsProject.instance().fileName()
```

will return the entire path to the file

```
'C:/MyDirectory/18809_US66.qgz'
```