# Get file path of Geopackage with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage, code-review

I want to get the Geopackage file path where my layer is stored in.

```
Layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DAT')[0]
print(Layer.source())
```

But this only gives me the path with layer pointer:

```
/home/.../DAT.gpkg|layername=DAT
```

My approach was to do:

```
Layer = Layer.source().split("|")[0]
```

It works, but is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting path of project, or layer file in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/getting-path-of-project-or-layer-file-in-pyqgis), where you may be interested in this approach: `>>>layerProvider = layer.dataProvider()` `>>>FilePath = layerProvider.dataSourceUri()` `>>>FilePath = os.path.dirname(unicode(FilePath))`

Comment: I believe that's about right. Pretty similar than to get the data provider and its uri `dp = my_lyr.dataProvider() print(dp.uri())`.